# What are the supported file formats of getMimeTypeFromExtension() in android

Tags: android, listview, mediastore

I'm creating an app where in i want to list all pdf, docx, xlsx, pptx, txt in a listview.

and this is what i've done so far.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

    String[] projection ={ MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE} ;

    String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("txt");
    String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{ mimeType};
    String sortOrder = null;

    Cursor allPdfFiles = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, sortOrder);


    if (allPdfFiles.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            ImageViewInfo newVVI = new ImageViewInfo();
            int id = allPdfFiles.getInt(allPdfFiles.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID));


            newVVI.filePath = allPdfFiles.getString(allPdfFiles.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA));
            newVVI.title = allPdfFiles.getString(allPdfFiles.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE));
            newVVI.mimeType = allPdfFiles.getString(allPdfFiles.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE));
            ImageRows.add(newVVI);
        } while (allPdfFiles.moveToNext());


        allPdfFiles.close();

    }
```

I'm having problem in getting the other file format like docx, xlsx, pptx for example when i try to change it `String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("docx");` it always return null

but when it is `getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")` or `getMimeTypeFromExtension("txt")` its working fine.

what are the supported file formats of `getMimeTypeFromExtension()`?

what should i do? can you point out where am I doing wrong? if possible can you suggest a solution for it. thank you in advance! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what are the supported file formats of getMimeTypeFromExtension()?

That will vary by Android OS version, and possibly by device if manufacturers have gone in and tinkered with it. For example, [the definitions from 7.1.2](http://xref.opersys.com/android-7.1.2_r11/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java) differ from [those from 4.1.2](http://xref.opersys.com/android-4.1.2_r2.1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java), such as 7.1.2 having `webp`.

> what should i do?

Hard-code them in your own app.

Comment: thanks man! after I read your comment, i try to run my app on other devices both are running on Android lollipop, but different brands. in my conclusion it really depends on the manufacturer. you've enlightened me in this one thank you very much! I really appreciate it.

so I'm going to hard code them, how can i do it? can you give me an example?

Comment: @asgardwin7: Um, well, MIME types are just strings. So, provide your own definitions in your code. `MimeTypeMap` is more for cases when you do not know what file types you have at compile time.

Comment: um, while i'm trying it on another android device that runs on android 6.0 it happens that theres an error in this line `Cursor allPdfFiles = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, sortOrder);` should i create another post here to ask this question?

Comment: i tried to search for it in the internet and found that android 6.0 does not support media queries [link](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6149-android-6-0-media-queries-column-stacking)

Comment: @asgardwin7: "media queries" refer to Web development and CSS and are not related to your issue. I do recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide a [mcve] with your code and the full stack trace of your error.

Comment: nice! okay i'll do that :) thank you very much for your answers I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is use the LIKE operator in your query. Mime types are held as strings in the media database so you can just select them. You are interested in all text files so string beginning with  "text/". Amend your selection

```
 String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " LIKE?";
 String mimeType = "txt/";
```

note: make sure there is a space between MIME.TYPE and the operator.